# How to find and highlight values outside two standard deviations for multiple measurement/std dev sets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, statistics

So I know about conditional formatting and countif type ways to do this, but they won't work with my scenario. I have 120 rows with 3 measurements per row. With those three measurements I have an average and a standard deviation, and I would like to highlight or otherwise identify any of those values that don't fit into two standard deviations of the mean (or median, I'm going to look at both).

I can't find any way to do conditional formatting or countif that has a dynamic row number for the criteria section. Example table below:

| amm | amm | amm | amm | amm | med | med+2std | med-2std | avg+2Std | avg-2Std |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | avg | stdev |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| area/(slope*MM | area/(slope*MM | area/(slope*MM | um | um |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0.553481048 | 0.537202194 | 0.874407034 | 0.655030092 | 0.190160281 | 0.553481048 | 0.93380161 | 0.173160486 | 1.035350654 | 0.27470953 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0.179067398 | 0.258136119 | 0.651154174 | 0.362785897 | 0.252844148 | 0.258136119 | 0.763824415 | -0.247552177 | 0.868474193 | -0.142902399 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0.432552416 | 0.534876643 | 0.723246244 | 0.563558434 | 0.147454092 | 0.534876643 | 0.829784827 | 0.239968459 | 0.858466618 | 0.26865025 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0.886034787 | 1.00928897 | 1.160449761 | 1.018591173 | 0.13744378 | 1.00928897 | 1.28417653 | 0.73440141 | 1.293478733 | 0.743703613 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -0.413948011 | 0.201392684 | 0.683711883 | 0.157052185 | 0.550171674 | 0.201392684 | 1.301736032 | -0.898950664 | 1.257395533 | -0.943291163 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0.186276605 | 0.152323566 | 0.40929691 | 0.249299027 | 0.139598331 | 0.186276605 | 0.465473267 | -0.092920057 | 0.528495689 | -0.029897635 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with conditional formatting:

```
=OR(A5>$G5,A5<$H5,A5>$I5,A5<$J5)
```

[image]

Set the Applies To range correctly:

[image]

It would be better if you just create a column with the same formula, so that you have TRUE/FALSE on each row indicating whether that row contains an outlier or not.

Separately from the Excel stuff, I would advise against trying to test for outliers among three values generally and more specifically using this particular method.

Comment: Thanks; I found that it doesn't even really exclude anything since there are only 3 values. Is standard deviation from the median not typically used either?

Comment: As a general rule, you would expect around 30 observations to make the mean +/- X stdev test useful. You may also need to transform the data to a normal distribution first for it to even be useful with many thousands of observations. Another test that's a little more robust is median +/- 1.5 * IQR. You can read more about it here: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-interquartile-range-rule-3126244

Comment: I should add of course that you likely won't be able to calculate an IQR with just three observations. Are you sure you want to calculate these statistics row-wise and not on columns?